# Translating from Matlab: New problems (complex ginzburg landau equation

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

Thank you for all of your constructive criticisim on my last post. I have made some changes, but alas my code is still not working and I can't figure out why. What happens when I run this version is that I get a runtime warning about invalid errors encountered in matmul.
 My code is given as

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz


def poldif(*arg):
    """
    Calculate differentiation matrices on arbitrary nodes.
    Returns the differentiation matrices D1, D2, .. DM corresponding to the
    M-th derivative of the function f at arbitrarily specified nodes. The
    differentiation matrices can be computed with unit weights or
    with specified weights.
    Parameters
    ----------
    x       : ndarray
              vector of N distinct nodes
    M       : int
              maximum order of the derivative, 0 < M <= N - 1
    OR (when computing with specified weights)
    x       : ndarray
              vector of N distinct nodes
    alpha   : ndarray
              vector of weight values alpha(x), evaluated at x = x_j.
    B       : int
              matrix of size M x N, where M is the highest derivative required.
              It should contain the quantities B[l,j] = beta_{l,j} =
              l-th derivative of log(alpha(x)), evaluated at x = x_j.
    Returns
    -------
    DM : ndarray
         M x N x N  array of differentiation matrices
    Notes
    -----
    This function returns  M differentiation matrices corresponding to the
    1st, 2nd, ... M-th derivates on arbitrary nodes specified in the array
    x. The nodes must be distinct but are, otherwise, arbitrary. The
    matrices are constructed by differentiating N-th order Lagrange
    interpolating polynomial that passes through the speficied points.
    The M-th derivative of the grid function f is obtained by the matrix-
    vector multiplication
    .. math::
    f^{(m)}_i = D^{(m)}_{ij}f_j
    This function is based on code by Rex Fuzzle
    https://github.com/RexFuzzle/Python-Library
    References
    ----------
    ..[1] B. Fornberg, Generation of Finite Difference Formulas on Arbitrarily
    Spaced Grids, Mathematics of Computation 51, no. 184 (1988): 699-706.
    ..[2] J. A. C. Weidemann and S. C. Reddy, A MATLAB Differentiation Matrix
    Suite, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 26, (2000) : 465-519
    """
    if len(arg) > 3:
        raise Exception('number of arguments is either two OR three')

    if len(arg) == 2:
        # unit weight function : arguments are nodes and derivative order
        x, M = arg[0], arg[1]
        N = np.size(x)
        # assert M<N, "Derivative order cannot be larger or equal to number of points"
        if M >= N:
            raise Exception("Derivative order cannot be larger or equal to number of points")
        alpha = np.ones(N)
        B = np.zeros((M, N))

    elif len(arg) == 3:
        # specified weight function : arguments are nodes, weights and B  matrix
        x, alpha, B = arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]
        N = np.size(x)
        M = B.shape[0]

    I = np.eye(N)  # identity matrix
    L = np.logical_or(I, np.zeros(N))  # logical identity matrix
    XX = np.transpose(np.array([x, ] * N))
    DX = XX - np.transpose(XX)  # DX contains entries x(k)-x(j)
    DX[L] = np.ones(N)  # put 1's one the main diagonal
    c = alpha * np.prod(DX, 1)  # quantities c(j)
    C = np.transpose(np.array([c, ] * N))
    C = C / np.transpose(C)  # matrix with entries c(k)/c(j).
    Z = 1 / DX  # Z contains entries 1/(x(k)-x(j)
    Z[L] = 0  # eye(N)*ZZ;                # with zeros on the diagonal.
    X = np.transpose(np.copy(Z))  # X is same as Z', but with ...
    Xnew = X

    for i in range(0, N):
        Xnew[i:N - 1, i] = X[i + 1:N, i]

    X = Xnew[0:N - 1, :]  # ... diagonal entries removed
    Y = np.ones([N - 1, N])  # initialize Y and D matrices.
    D = np.eye(N)  # Y is matrix of cumulative sums

    DM = np.empty((M, N, N))  # differentiation matrices

    for ell in range(1, M + 1):
        Y = np.cumsum(np.vstack((B[ell - 1, :], ell * (Y[0:N - 1, :]) * X)), 0)  # diags
        D = ell * Z * (C * np.transpose(np.tile(np.diag(D), (N, 1))) - D)  # off-diags
        D[L] = Y[N - 1, :]
        DM[ell - 1, :, :] = D

    return DM

def herdif(N, M, b=1):
    """
    Calculate differentiation matrices using Hermite collocation.
    Returns the differentiation matrices D1, D2, .. DM corresponding to the
    M-th derivative of the function f, at the N Chebyshev nodes in the
    interval [-1,1].
    Parameters
    ----------
    N   : int
          number of grid points
    M   : int
          maximum order of the derivative, 0 < M < N
    b   : float, optional
          scale parameter, real and positive
    Returns
    -------
    x  : ndarray
         N x 1 array of Hermite nodes which are zeros of the N-th degree
         Hermite polynomial, scaled by b
    DM : ndarray
         M x N x N  array of differentiation matrices
    Notes
    -----
    This function returns  M differentiation matrices corresponding to the
    1st, 2nd, ... M-th derivates on a Hermite grid of N points. The
    matrices are constructed by differentiating N-th order Hermite
    interpolants.
    The M-th derivative of the grid function f is obtained by the matrix-
    vector multiplication
    .. math::
    f^{(m)}_i = D^{(m)}_{ij}f_j
    References
    ----------
    ..[1] B. Fornberg, Generation of Finite Difference Formulas on Arbitrarily
    Spaced Grids, Mathematics of Computation 51, no. 184 (1988): 699-706.
    ..[2] J. A. C. Weidemann and S. C. Reddy, A MATLAB Differentiation Matrix
    Suite, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 26, (2000) : 465-519
    ..[3] R. Baltensperger and M. R. Trummer, Spectral Differencing With A
    Twist, SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing 24, (2002) : 1465-1487
    """
    if M >= N - 1:
        raise Exception('number of nodes must be greater than M - 1')

    if M <= 0:
        raise Exception('derivative order must be at least 1')

    x = herroots(N)  # compute Hermite nodes
    alpha = np.exp(-x * x / 2)  # compute Hermite  weights.

    beta = np.zeros([M + 1, N])

    # construct beta(l,j) = d^l/dx^l (alpha(x)/alpha'(x))|x=x_j recursively
    beta[0, :] = np.ones(N)
    beta[1, :] = -x

    for ell in range(2, M + 1):
        beta[ell, :] = -x * beta[ell - 1, :] - (ell - 1) * beta[ell - 2, :]

    # remove initialising row from beta
    beta = np.delete(beta, 0, 0)

    # compute differentiation matrix (b=1)
    DM = poldif(x, alpha, beta)
    # scale nodes by the factor b
    x = x / b

    # scale the matrix by the factor b
    for ell in range(M):
        DM[ell, :, :] = (b ** (ell + 1)) * DM[ell, :, :]

    return x, DM

def herroots(N):
    """
    Compute roots of the Hermite polynomial of degree N
    Parameters
     ----------
    N   : int
          degree of the Hermite polynomial
    Returns
    -------
    x  : ndarray
         N x 1 array of Hermite roots
    """

    # Jacobi matrix
    d = np.sqrt(np.arange(1, N))
    J = np.diag(d, 1) + np.diag(d, -1)

    # compute eigenvalues
    mu = eig(J)[0]

    # return sorted, normalised eigenvalues
    # real part only since all roots must be real.
    return np.real(np.sort(mu) / np.sqrt(2))


a = 1-1j
b = 2+0.2j
c1 = 0.34
c2 = 0.005

alpha1 = (4*c2/a)**0.25
alpha2 = b/2*a

Nx = 220;

# hermite differentiation matrices
[x,D] = herdif(Nx, 2, np.real(alpha1))
D1 = D[0,:]
D2 = D[1,:]

# integration weights
diff = np.diff(x)
#print(len(diff))
p = np.concatenate([np.zeros(1), diff])
q = np.concatenate([diff, np.zeros(1)])
w = (p + q)/2
Q = np.diag(w)

#Discretised operator
const = c1*np.diag(np.ones(len(x)))-c2*(np.diag(x)*np.diag(x))
#print(const)
A = a*D2 - b*D1 + const

##### Timestepping

tmax = 200
tmin = 0
dt = 1
n = (tmax - tmin)/dt
tvec = np.linspace(0,tmax,n, endpoint = True)

#(len(tvec))

q = np.zeros((Nx, len(tvec)),dtype=complex)
f = np.zeros((Nx, len(tvec)),dtype=complex)

q0 = np.ones(Nx)*10**4
q[:,0] = q0
#print(q[:,0])
#print(q0)

# qnew - qold = dt*Aqold + dt*N(qold,qold,qold)
# qnew - qold = dt*Aqnew - dt*N(qold,qold,qold)
# therefore qnew - qold = 0.5*dtAqold + 0.5*dt*Aqnew + dtN(qold,qold,qold)
# rearranging to give qnew( 1- 0.5Adt) = (1 + 0.5Adt) + dt N(qold,qold,qold)

from numpy.linalg import inv

inverted = inv(np.eye(Nx)-0.5*A*dt)
forqold = (np.eye(Nx) + 0.5*A*dt)
firstterm = np.matmul(inverted,forqold)

for t in range(0, len(tvec)-1):
    nl = abs(np.square(q[:,t]))*q[:,t]
    q[:,t+1] = np.matmul(firstterm,q[:,t]) - dt*np.matmul(inverted,nl)
```

where the hermitedifferentiation matrices can be found online and are in a different file. This code blows up after five interations, which I cannot understand as I don't see how it differs in the matlab found here https://www.bagherigroup.com/research/open-source-codes/

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the actual code and error instead of print screens.

Comment: A photo of a computer screen is the worst possible choice. That being said you're probably just missing that in numpy `*` is elementwise multiplication and `@` is matrix multiplication... If that's not the problem you'll have to give us _complete_ code anyway, see also [mcve].

Comment: Will do guys :) will have to wait for internet tomorrow!

Comment: On top of what @AndrasDeak said, I’ll add that loops are rarely necessary with NumPy and should be a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with code. Now you're saying "still not working" and "there are new problems". These are never sufficieny information. We can only help you debug problems that you tell us. This is included in a [mcve]. Also input files from sites outside Stack Overflow are again bad, because links can (and will) rot, and your question won't make sense five years from now. Please reduce the problem to a size that you can post here completely. Again, this is all what's needed for a [mcve].

Comment: The code should be fully reproducible now, simply by copying and pasting. Thanks

Comment: OK, I can run your code and observe the behaviour you're seeing. Such an iteration can diverge for a number of reasons. The matrix you're multiplying with isn't remotely singular, so the term that explodes is the second one that contains `nl`. Unsurprisingly, `|q|^2*q` will be huge if `q` has values of 10^4. Shouldn't there be some kind of normalization for `q`, assuming it's something like a superconducting wave function? Without seeing the actual equation you're trying to implement it won't be easy to fix the physics. Did this use to work in MATLAB? Aren't you missing a normalization step?

Comment: I have just looked at the initial conditions and it was supposed to be 10^(-4). This seems to have fixed the problem! Thankk you for all of your help. :)

Comment: You really should have posted a new question, since the original problem was solved (with the `matmul`).

Comment: I was not allowed to by stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Error in:

```
q[:,t+1] = inverted*forgold*np.array(q[:,t]) + inverted*dt*np.array(nl)
```

`q[:, t+1]` indexes a 2d array (probably not a `np.matrix` which is more MATLAB like).  This indexing reduces the number of dimensions by 1, hence the (220,) shape in the error message.

The error message says the RHS is (220,220).  That shape probably comes from `inverted` and `forgold`.  `np.array(q[:,t])` is 1d.  Multiplying a (220,220) by a (220,) is ok, but you can't put that square array into a 1d slot.

Both uses of `np.array` in the error line are superfluous.  Their arguments are already `ndarray`.

As for the loop, it may be necessary.  It looks like `q[:,t+1]` is a function of q[:,t]`, a serial, rather than parallel operation.  Those are harder to render as 'vectorized' (unless you can use`cumsum` like operations).

Note that in `numpy` `*` is elementwise multiplication, the `.*` of MATLAB.  `np.dot` and `@` are used for matrix multiplication.

```
q[:,t+1]= invert@q[:,t]
```

would work

Comment: What's with the downvote?  This is an answer to the initial question, with the screen shot.  The posted code changes the multiplication to use `matmul`, which I suggested.